# How placing intermediate stiffeners closer increase strength of girders?

Tags: structural-engineering

How does placing intermediate stiffeners closer increases strength of plate girders?

Comment: Did you improve this question after having the others closed?

Answer (score 1):

The plate girder is a deep beam built up from plates. It is prone to buckling and distortion since, for economic reasons, the web plate is usually kept thin with a very high d/t (depth/thickness) ratio.

For compression buckling concerns, the intermediate vertical stiffeners are utilized to stiffen the web plate. The stiffeners (usually) are placed at a regular interval, and the girder now looks/behaves a lot like a truss with the flanges as the chords, the stiffener as the compression member, and through tension field action, the web plate acts as the diagonal tension member. Note that the truss is a geometrically stable structure. Without the intermediate stiffeners, the web of the plate girder is too flexible, thus its stability is questionable, and its load-carrying capacity will be greatly reduced.

On top of preventing buckling, the stiffeners also provide the girder with better torsional restrain/resistance. And, a pair of stiffeners are usually provided under the concentrated load to better distribute the stress.